# How to uses a ToolStripContainer whith Dock=Fill on a MDI parent?

Tags: winforms, mdi

How to uses a ToolStripContainer whith Dock=Fill on a MDI parent???... When I drop a ToolStripContainer on a MDI parent and assing fill to a property Dock it hide  all the MDI children.

thanks...

Comment: I had the same problem, I found a solution here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229722.aspx#Y0

Answer (score 1):

try adding the MDI child form to the `ToolStripContainer`:

```
toolStripContainer1.ContentPanel.Controls.Add(frm);
```

Comment: That´s impossible, a MDI child Form is a control on a high level that a ToolStripContainer...

Thacks..

Comment: no it's possible, first make the form as MDIChild to your main form, then add it to the toolStripContainer, I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

the MDILayout doesn't work on the child forms